# How control media player in android across all activities?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hello friends i am creating a mp3 player which have two activities how can i control media from both activities like play pause and progress bar here is 
the first activity have list of the song when user click any songs it work fine  and below this song listview  i create progress and bar and media controll button like play pause and  next and back its include spreate layoute ad in below list when user click on this layout it redirect another activity and which have also same feature like play pause and and progress bar how can i controll this media from both activities?
my code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#1e1e2c"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/song_list"/>



  <include
  android:layout_below="@+id/song_title"
      layout="@layout/mediacontroller"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#1e1e2c"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/rotate"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/musiccirlce"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/repeat"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_repeat_white_48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.023"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/repeatenable"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/repeatenable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.023"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shuffle"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_shuffle_white_48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.976"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/shufflenable"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@drawable/shuffulenabled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.976"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@mipmap/outline_thumb_up_alt_black_48"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songtime"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.56"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2new"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@mipmap/baseline_thumb_up_alt_black_48"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/songtime"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.56"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@mipmap/baseline_thumb_down_alt_black_18"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endTime"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.56"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttontwo"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:src="@mipmap/baseline_thumb_down_alt_black_18"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/endTime"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.56"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/songtime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="1:05"

                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/endTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="3:06"

                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/play_button_main"
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:src="@drawable/play_button" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/pause_button_main"
                        android:layout_width="55dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:src="@drawable/pause_button" />
                </LinearLayout>





                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pervious"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/backword_button"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.754"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/next"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/forword_button"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                    />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>



package music.player.musicplayer;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    LinearLayout nextactivity;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        songView = findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        getSongList();

        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
            public int compare(Song a, Song b){
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });
        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);

        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        nextactivity=findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller);


        nextactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            }
        });


    }







//song info method retrive
    public void getSongList() {
        //retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int dataColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(dataColumn);

                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisPath));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}

package music.player.musicplayer;

public class Song {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String getpath;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getGetpath() {
        return getpath;
    }



    public Song(long id, String title, String artist, String getpath ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.getpath = getpath;

    }
}

package music.player.musicplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;

    public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs=theSongs;
        songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return songs.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       RelativeLayout songLay = (RelativeLayout)songInf.inflate(R.layout.song, parent, false);
        //get title and artist views
        TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);
        //get title and artist strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        //set position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }

    }
```

Here is  my activities picture you get idea what i actually i want

[image: activity 1:]

actity two:[image: activity 2:]